# Forecast Revenue Split by Attribute using R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am new to R so I apologize in advance if this question is rudimentary. I have a data set that is split into four columns (transaction_date, product_group, unit_segment_label, amount). Basically I want to run a linear model by product_group and unit_segment_label, meaning I want to be able to create a forecast for customers who appear in unit_segment_label = 0 and product_group = "Credit Card" separately from customers who appear in unit_segment_label = 1 and product_group = "Credit Card." If I subset the data at the beginning to the specification I am looking for the code works correctly but ideally I would like to run all scenarios through this one block of code without having to write out a subset for every scenario (see below).

```
temp <- fetch(input_ds)

#This filters the data to the product and customer segment
x <- subset(temp,temp$product_group %in% "Credit Card" & temp$unit_segment_label == 0)

#This creates a single variable based on the product group used.
v <- x$product_group[1]

#This creates a single variable based on the customer segment used.
u <- 0

x$date <- as.Date(x$transaction_date)
x$year <- as.numeric(format(x$transaction_date,'%Y'))
x$month <- format(x$transaction_date,'M%m')
x$dow <- format(x$transaction_date,"DW%u")
x.lm <- lm(amount ~ year + month + dow,data=x)
x$fitted <- predict(x.lm,x)

last_day <- as.Date(format(seq(from=max(x$date),by='month',length.out=2),'%Y-%m-01'))[2]-1
new_values <- data.frame(date=seq(from=min(x$date),to=last_day+(365*1),by='day'))

VariablePG <- "product_group"
new_values[, VariablePG] <- v
VariableCS <- "unit_segment_label"
new_values[, VariableCS] <- u

new_values$year <- as.numeric(format(new_values$date,'%Y'))
new_values$month <- format(new_values$date,'M%m')
new_values$dow <- format(new_values$date,"DW%u")
new_values$forecasts <- predict(x.lm,new_values)

CC <- select(merge(new_values,x,by=c('date','product_group','unit_segment_label'),all.x=TRUE),date,product_group,unit_segment_label,amount,forecasts)
```

I thought I could write it into a function and use ddply but it doesn't work as I expect, of course what I expect may be completely different from what ddply does. Below is the code I tried to write using ddply.

```
temp <- fetch(input_ds)
x <- subset(temp,temp$unit_segment_label == 0)

zero_tO_20_unit_function <- function(temp,product_group) {

y <- x

unit_segment_label <- y$unit_segment_label[1]
product_group <- unique(y$product_group)

y$date <- as.Date(y$transaction_date)
y$year <- as.numeric(format(y$transaction_date,'%Y'))
y$month <- format(y$transaction_date,'M%m')
y$dow <- format(y$transaction_date,"DW%u")
y.lm <- lm(amount ~ year + month + dow,data=y)
y$fitted <- predict(y.lm,y)

last_day <- as.Date(format(seq(from=max(y$date),by='month',length.out=2),'%Y-%m-01'))[2]-1
new_values_temp <- data.frame(date=seq(from=min(y$date),to=last_day+(365*1),by='day'),unit_segment_label)
new_values <- merge(new_values_temp,product_group,all=TRUE)
colnames(new_values)[3] <- "product_group"

new_values$year <- as.numeric(format(new_values$date,'%Y'))
new_values$month <- format(new_values$date,'M%m')
new_values$dow <- format(new_values$date,"DW%u")
new_values$forecasts <- predict(y.lm,new_values)

CC <- select(merge(new_values,y,by=c('date','product_group','unit_segment_label'),all.y=TRUE),date,product_group,unit_segment_label,amount,forecasts)

}

all_add_on <- ddply(temp,.(product_group), zero_tO_20_unit_function)
```

I am sure there is something I am missing where I can split the data, apply the alogorithm and then combine it back together. Any help and insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by`, the function that allows you to slice a dataframe into one or more multiple factors and pass each subset into a defined function to return a list of function's return objects (here being dataframes). Consider also `transform` and `within` for concise column assignment.

```
run_model <- function(x) {
    v <- x$product_group[[1]]      # product group used
    u <- x$customer_segment[[1]]   # customer segment used

    x <- transform(x, date = as.Date(transaction_date),
                      year = as.numeric(format(transaction_date, '%Y')),
                      month = format(transaction_date, 'M%m'),
                      dow = format(transaction_date, 'DW%u'))

    x.lm <- lm(amount ~ year + month + dow, data=x)
    x$fitted <- predict(x.lm, x)

    last_day <- as.Date(format(seq(from=max(x$date), by='month', length.out=2),
                               '%Y-%m-01'))[2]-1

    new_values <- data.frame(date=seq(from=min(x$date), to=last_day+(365*1), by='day'),
                             product_group = v,
                             unit_segment_label = u)

    new_values <- within(new_values, { year <- as.numeric(format(date, '%Y'))
                                       month <- format(date, 'M%m')
                                       dow <- format(date, 'DW%u')
                                       forecasts <- predict(x.lm, new_values)})

    CC <- merge(new_values, x, by=c('date', 'product_group', 'unit_segment_label'),
                all.x=TRUE)[c("date", "product_group", "unit_segment_label", 
                              "amount", "forecasts")]    
}

temp <- fetch(input_ds)

# This processes data for each product and customer segment
df_list <- by(temp, temp[, c("product_group", "unit_segment_label")], run_model)
# Combine all df subsets into one final df
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```